# WPF apply triggers to listview items to change background

Tags: wpf, xaml, listboxitem

I am trying to create a sort of left menu for navigation inside the desktopapplication. My idea is to use Buttons as Listview items which should behave in this way: when i hover with the mouseover them theri background should change color (becomes darkCyan) and when i click one its background color should change persistently (to darkCyan) until i click on another button of the list. The problem is that i am using a the DataTemplate property to specify how the buttons should look like and I am tryin to apply the triggers to change the background color on the ControlTemplate of the ListView. The result is that sometimes the background color changes but the command related to the button is not fired other times the contrary. I think that I am doing the things in the wrong element of the tree view, but I don't have enough knowledge of the tree view so I am not understanding what I am doing wrong. Here is the code of the XAML in which i define the styles for the Buttons and the ListView

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:TripViewModel}">
        <views:TripView />
    </DataTemplate>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Height"
                Value="50" />
        <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="#555D6F" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border>
                        <Grid Background="Transparent">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                              VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="Transparent"
                            BorderThickness="0"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                                 Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background"
                                    Value="DarkCyan" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                                 Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background"
                                    Value="DarkCyan" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

And here is the code in which I create the ListView

```
<ListView Name="MenuButtons"
      ItemsSource="{Binding PageViewModels}"
      Background="Transparent"
      IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding Name}"
                    Command="{Binding DataContext.ChangePageCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                    Margin="0" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Anyone can help?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue by using a ListBox instead of a ListView and setting the ItemContainer to be a button in the following way

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemContainerTemplate>
        <Button Content="{Binding Name}"
                Command="{Binding DataContext.ChangePageCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                Margin="0" />
    </ItemContainerTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```